# Get all files required in node.js program

Tags: node.js

Is there some way to get list of files there where required (with require("...")) by node process?

UPD, solution:
module object itself contains links to all required children modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loaded modules are stored in require.cache object. You should be able to check that to see whats been loaded with require().

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#require.cache

Comment: Actually I've found other solution that works for me: module object itself contains links to all required children modules. Thanks!